# Getting the error [Dagger/MissingBinding]

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I have been following the GithubBrowserSample from Google as my reference.

I have just put the final touches to dagger by implmenting into my MainActivity and now receive the following error. Can't seem to find an awful lot on it other than include what I already have in there.

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment>>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment>>> is injected at
dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector.<init>(…, injectorFactoriesWithStringKeys)
dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector<androidx.fragment.app.Fragment> is injected at
com.crosscare.MainActivity.dispatchingAndroidInjector
com.crosscare.MainActivity is injected at
dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)
component path: com.crosscare.di.AppComponent ? com.crosscare.di.MainActivityModule_ContributeMainActivity.MainActivitySubcomponent
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> dispatchingAndroidInjector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> supportFragmentInjector() {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```

AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidInjectionModule.class,
        AppModule.class,
        MainActivityModule.class
})
public interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance Builder application(Application application);
        AppComponent build();
    }
    void inject(CrosscareApp crosscareApp);
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue after more carefully googling.

Seems for androidx I need to use AndroidSupportInjectionModule instead of AndroidInjectionModule